# How can I wrap text within a multiline table, without loosing formatting?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, text-processing

I have data (mostly log, but also user notes) in form of:

```
[2019_03_10][21:12:55] # Very useful text of hight iportance to demonstrate my question.
[2019_03_10][22:32:55] #  Another Text.
[2019_03_10][23:02:22] #  blablabal Bla bla, just another long text with linebreak. And this one is just a little longer then those before.
```

At the moment, I use `cat test.txt | column -s '#' -t` and that's what I get:

```
[2019_03_10][21:12:55]   Very useful text of hight iportance 
to demonstrate my question. 
[2019_03_10][22:32:55]    Another Text.
[2019_03_10][23:02:22]    blablabal Bla bla, just another lon
g text with linebreak. And this one is just a little longer t
hen those before.
```

Thats what I would love to get:

```
[2019_03_10][21:12:55]   Very useful text of hight iportance 
                          to demonstrate my question. 
[2019_03_10][22:32:55]    Another Text.
[2019_03_10][23:02:22]    blablabal Bla bla, just another lon
                          g text with linebreak. And this one 
                          is just a little longer then those 
                          before.
```

There must be an easy way of doing this. Must not?

Comment: Could you please provide the original `test.txt` content?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take advantage of the UNIX command `fold` so you don't have to reinvent the wheel:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    beg = end = $0
    sub(/ *#.*/,"",beg)
    sub(/[^#]+# */,"",end)

    cmd = "printf \047" end "\n\047 | fold -sw38"
    while ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        print beg, line
        gsub(/./," ",beg)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
[2019_03_10][21:12:55] Very useful text of hight iportance
                       to demonstrate my question.
[2019_03_10][22:32:55] Another Text.
[2019_03_10][23:02:22] blablabal Bla bla, just another long
                       text with linebreak. And this one is
                       just a little longer then those
                       before.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl script that uses the standard [Text::Wrap](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Wrap.html) module:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use Text::Wrap;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my $line = wrap("", "\t\t\t", $_);
  $line =~ s/ # /\t/;
  say $line;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ perl wrap.pl test.txt
[2019_03_10][21:12:55]  Very useful text of hight iportance to demonstrate
                        my question.
```

One-liner version:

```
$ perl -MText::Wrap -lpe '$_ = wrap("", "\t\t\t", $_); s/ # /\t/;' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
WIDTH=50                                    # width of column2 
# TMPFILE=$(mktemp)                         # tempfile in /tmp
TMPFILE=$(mktemp -p /dev/shm)               # tempfile in shared memory
while read line; do                         # read all lines from log
    column1=${line%%#*}                     # extract column1
    blank=${column1//?/ }                   # blankline, size len(column1)
    column2=${line##*#}                     # column2, comments
    echo $column2 | fmt -$WIDTH > $TMPFILE  # format column2
    while read line2; do                    # read new formated lines
        echo  "$column1" $line2             # write column1 and column2
        column1=$blank                      # blank column1
    done < $TMPFILE                         # read from tempfile
done < "$1"                                 # first arg from commandline
rm $TMPFILE                                 # delete tempfile
```

USAGE: scriptname logfile

If you have no shared memory you can replace line 4 with line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl command line. You can change 20 to 30 or 40 to wrap the length you need.

```
$ perl -ne ' ($x,$y)=/(.+?)#(.+)/ ; print "$x"; $s=""; 
   while($y=~/(.{20,}?\s|.*$)/g) { printf("%s%s\n",$s,$1);$s="\t\t\t" } ' mac.txt
[2019_03_10][21:12:55]  Very useful text of
                        hight iportance to demonstrate
                        my question.

[2019_03_10][22:32:55]  Another Text.

[2019_03_10][23:02:22]  blablabal Bla bla, just
                        another long text with
                        linebreak. And this one
                        is just a little longer
                        then those before.


$
```

There is an extra newline, if you want to remove that

```
$ perl -lne ' ($x,$y)=/(.+?)#(.+)/ ; printf("%s",$x); $s=""; 
   while($y=~/(.{20,}?\s|.*$)/g) { $p=$1; print $s,$p if $p!~/^\s*$/s; $s="\t\t\t" } ' mac.txt
[2019_03_10][21:12:55]  Very useful text of
                        hight iportance to demonstrate
                        my question.
[2019_03_10][22:32:55]  Another Text.
[2019_03_10][23:02:22]  blablabal Bla bla, just
                        another long text with
                        linebreak. And this one
                        is just a little longer
                        then those before.

$
```